# php script does not email me the form contents

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following php script and it is supposed to send me the contents as an email when someone submits. It works perfectly for validations and also submits succesfully if no errors are there but I never receive emails, What is wrong with this. Any help is appreciated. I am testing this page on localhost:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "mike8978wade@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Enquiry Form";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps remove the `@` in front of mail to not suppress warnings? Also, try outputting each variable (`$email_to, $email_subject, ... `) to see what is being passed to `mail`.

Comment: then what should be there. you mean this line should not have @ 
$email_to = "mike8978wade@gmail.com";

Comment: `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);` - that line. Remove the @.

Comment: The `@` at `@mail($email_to ... ` suppresses warnings.

Comment: @TerrySeidler: that worked but now I am getting this:
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\learn\email_form.php on line 69
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

Comment: Check your configuration between your php interpreter and your smtp server or sendmail in your php.ini  Also check the spam folder on the destination inbox of the email you are testing.

Comment: and there is no function.mail file in localhost

Comment: strongly recommend avoiding using the PHP `mail()` function. It's complex to use, difficult to debug, and easy to leave it open to security holes. I suggest using the [phpMailer class](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) instead.

Comment: @Spudley: Can you please help with this. How do I get this form to submit

Comment: Remove the variable $email_from from the header or sanitize it. You shouldn't put user input into an email header, unless you want your form to become a spam bot and get shutdown by your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your smtp settings in the php.ini file.

Also some mail services may refuse to accept the email for some time since they "check" the sender address.

Comment: where do I find these setting and what should be there for this to work

Answer (score 1):

It is quite likely that your PHP is fine.

Your `localhost`, development machine, probably doesn't have it's own mail server configured.

To set this up:

Mac - [Setup a testing mail server using PHP on Mac OS X](http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/12/03/setup-a-testing-mail-server-using-php-on-mac-os-x/)

PC - [PHP Sendmail Setup with SMTP IIS and Windows Servers](http://www.ruhanirabin.com/php-sendmail-setup-with-smtp-iis-and-windows-servers/)

**Easiest** thing to do is to push this script to a test site with it's mail server already configured.

Comment: I also upoloaded this on my wordpress site but it didn't work there too.